# Darle valor a un atributo apartir de un TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql

Tengo las columnas `mesesAtraso` y es de tipo **INT()**, tambien `FechaUltimoPago` de tipo **Date()**.

> Como puedo hacer para que con un **TIMESTAMPDIFF** le de valor a `mesesdeatraso`?

Realizando la siguiente consulta me da el valor que quiero asignarle pero no se como seguir.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechaUltPago, CURDATE()) AS mesesatraso from socio;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardarlo en una variable de esta manera

```
Select @mesesdeatraso := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechaUltPago, CURDATE()) from socio;
```

Luego usas la variable @mesesdeatraso segun sea tu caso, un update o insert

```
Update tabla SET mesesdeatraso = @mesesdeatraso
Insert tabla (mesesdeatraso) VALUES @mesesdeatraso
```